# Is this simple UPDATE SQL an error waiting to happen? How to rewrite it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to examine ACCT_NUMS values om TABLE_1. If the ACCT_NUM is prefixed by "GF0", then I need to disregard the "GF0" prefix and take the rightmost 7 characters of the remaining string. If this resulting value is not found in account_x_master or CW_CLIENT_STAGE, then, the record is to be flagged as an error.

The following seems to do the trick, but I have a concern...

```
UPDATE
    table_1
SET
    Error_Ind = 'GW001'
WHERE
    LEFT(ACCT_NUM, 3) = 'GF0'
    AND RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3), 7) NOT IN           
    (
        SELECT
            acct_num
        FROM
            account_x_master
    ) 
    AND RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3), 7) NOT IN              
    (                                   
        SELECT                          
            CW_CLIENT_STAGE.AGS_NUM     
        FROM                            
            dbo.CW_CLIENT_STAGE         
    )
```

My concern is that SQL Server may attempt to perform a SUBSTRING operation

```
SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3)
```

that results in a computed negative value and causing the SQL to fail. Of course, this wouldn't fail is the SUBSTRING operation were only applied to those records that we at least 3 characters long, which would always be the case if the

```
LEFT(ACCT_NUM, 3) = 'GF0'
```

were applied first. If possible, I'd like to avoid adding new columns to the table. Bonus points for simplicity and less overhead :-)

How can I rewrite this UPDATE SQL to protect against this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people said, your concern is valid.

I'd make two changes to your query.

1) To avoid having negative value in the `SUBSTRING` parameter we can rewrite it using `STUFF`:

```
SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3)
```

is equivalent to:

```
STUFF(ACCT_NUM, 1, 3, '')
```

Instead of extracting a tail of a string we replace first three characters with empty string. If the string is shorter than 3 characters, result is empty string.

By the way, if your `ACCT_NUM` may end with space(s), they will be trimmed by the `SUBSTRING` version, because `LEN` doesn't count trailing spaces.

2) Instead of

```
LEFT(ACCT_NUM, 3) = 'GF0'
```

use:

```
ACCT_NUM LIKE 'GF0%'
```

If you have an index on `ACCT_NUM` and only relatively small number of rows start with `GF0`, then index will be used. If you use a function, such as `LEFT`, index can't be used.

So, the final query becomes:

```
UPDATE
    table_1
SET
    Error_Ind = 'GW001'
WHERE
    ACCT_NUM LIKE 'GF0%'
    AND RIGHT(STUFF(ACCT_NUM, 1, 3, ''), 7) NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            acct_num
        FROM
            account_x_master
    ) 
    AND RIGHT(STUFF(ACCT_NUM, 1, 3, ''), 7) NOT IN
    (                                   
        SELECT                          
            CW_CLIENT_STAGE.AGS_NUM     
        FROM                            
            dbo.CW_CLIENT_STAGE         
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a very valid concern, because SQL Server will rearrange the order of evaluation of expressions in the `WHERE`.

The only way to guarantee the order of operations in a SQL statement is to use `case`.  I don't think there is a way to catch failing calls to `substring()` . . . there is no `try_substring()` analogous to `try_convert()`.

So:

```
WHERE
    LEFT(ACCT_NUM, 3) = 'GF0' AND
    (CASE WHEN LEN(ACCT_NUM) > 3 THEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3), 7) END) NOT IN (SELECT acct_num
                      FROM account_x_master
                     ) AND
    (CASE WHEN LEN(ACCT_NUM) > 3 THEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3), 7) END) NOT IN (SELECT CW_CLIENT_STAGE.AGS_NUM     
                      FROM dbo.CW_CLIENT_STAGE         
                     )
```

This is uglier.  And, there may be ways around it, say by using `LIKE` with wildcards rather than string manipulation.  But, the `case` will guarantee that the `SUBSTRING()` is only run on strings long enough so no error is generated.

Comment: It's worse than that; in versions of SQL prior to 2012 (and possibly even in higher versions) even `CASE` may not short-circuit deterministically in all situations:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2011/03/03/don-t-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case.aspx

Comment: In this case it is possible to avoid the problem altogether by using `STUFF` instead of `SUBSTRING`, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query.
Since there is no short circuit `and or` in SQL `WHERE` clause, only way to achieve is via `CASE` syntax.

I noticed that you had two `NOT IN` comparisons in different parts of `WHERE` which I combined into one.
Note that `CASE` condition is `>=3` and not `>3`, as `RIGHT('',x)` is allowed.
Also note the proper use of `CASE` with `NOT IN`

```
UPDATE     table_1
SET
    Error_Ind = 'GW001'
    select * from table_1
WHERE
    LEFT(ACCT_NUM, 3) = 'GF0'
     AND CASE 
            WHEN LEN(ACCT_NUM)>=3 
            THEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ACCT_NUM, 4, LEN(ACCT_NUM) - 3), 7)
            ELSE NULL END NOT IN           
                (
                SELECT  acct_num as num
                    FROM    account_x_master
                UNION 
                SELECT  CW_CLIENT_STAGE.AGS_NUM   as num
                    FROM   dbo.CW_CLIENT_STAGE         
                )
```